# Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: TimeOfDay. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive, build-runner

I am trying to add data to my hive box. I have initialised hive, opened the box and then added data into the box. However I get an error asking stating that TimeOfDay is an unknown time although I have already registered/built a time adapter. I have attached part of my code below, can someone figure out the issue?

task_model.g.dart

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'task_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class TasksModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<TasksModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  TasksModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return TasksModel(
      taskDetails: fields[0] as String,
      isChecked: fields[1] as bool,
      priority: fields[2] as String,
      time: fields[3] as TimeOfDay,
      date: fields[4] as DateTime,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, TasksModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.taskDetails)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.isChecked)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.priority)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.time)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.date);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is TasksModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

task_model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'task_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class TasksModel{
  @HiveField(0)
  String taskDetails;

  @HiveField(1)
  bool isChecked = false;

  @HiveField(2)
  String priority;

  @HiveField(3)
  TimeOfDay time;

  @HiveField(4)
  DateTime date;

  TasksModel({@required this.taskDetails, @required this.isChecked, @required this.priority, @required this.time, @required this.date});

  void toggle(){
    isChecked = !isChecked;
  }
}
```

Creating a new task

```
void addNewTask(TasksModel data){
    final taskBox = Hive.box('todoTasks');
    taskBox.add(data);
  }

final newTask = TasksModel(taskDetails: taskName, isChecked: false, priority: priorityVal, time: _time, date: _date);
addNewTask(newTask);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate Adapters for `TimeOfDay` class as well then register it

Comment: I have registered it by adding the following line in the main() class - Hive.registerAdapter(TasksModelAdapter());

Comment: yes but TasksModel has an attribute of TimeOfDay which is also an object, you need an adapter so that Hive will know how to handle TimeOfDay also.

Comment: @Vortenzie Hive can only [handle primitive data types, lists and maps](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/206#issuecomment-580628461). Objects such as `TimeOfDay` require an adapter. Hopefully [this solution](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/206#issuecomment-582304488) works for you too. If not, you could try modifying that to taste

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown as **TimeOfDay is not an implicit datatype provided by dart**.
To fix this similar to TasksModel class definition there should be a definition of TimeOfDay class defining it's blueprint and contains the hivetype as well as hivefield for each property of TimeOfDay class.
Finally **register** the **TimeOfDayAdapter** after using **hive generator** same as TasksModelAdapter

Comment: I would also like to add that `@HiveField(4)
  DateTime date;` here DateTime datatype is itself capable to store time. But still, if you need a custom time datatype then you'll have to use hive generator in TimeOfDay class definition .